# Getting the runtime reference of the button and text view layed on dynamically within a for loop in android

Tags: android-layout

I am Inflating a custom view in In an Android activity dynamically  using a for loop. The view contains an array of button and array of text view. On clicking the button a date picker Dialog opens which has been registered to the button on click listener. I want to set the date in the text view corresponding to the button which have been clicked. Please suggest me some solution its very urgent. I am not able to get the runtime reference of the text view which is to be updated after the date picker dialog set.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand that the buttons and text views are supposed to be somehow related, right? So how about extending the Button class (lets say you call it ButtonWithTextView) and including a reference to the TextView that you want to associate with that Button. So every time you fire the View.onClick listener, you'll be able to cast the View to your class and retrieve that TextView reference.

An example:

```
class ButtonWithTextView extends Button {
    TextView tv;
    ButtonWithTextView(Context c, TextView tv) {
        super(c);
        this.tv = tv;
    }

    TextView getAssociatedTextView() {
        return tv;
    }
}

.
.
.

//somewhere in your code

TextView tv1 = new TextView(context);
ButtonWithTextView button1 = new ButtonWithTextView(context, tv1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ButtonWithTextView button = (ButtonWithTextView)v;
        TextView associatedTextView = button.getAssociatedTextView();
        .
        .
        .
    }
});
```